# CKContainer does not have a member named 'publicCloudDatabase'

Tags: swift

```
var defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer
var publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase
```

For second line compiler says CKContainer does not have a member named 'publicCloudDatabase'

But it has, see [CKContainer API](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CKContainer/publicCloudDatabase). What is the problem, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer() // <- need ()
var publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase
```

**defaultContainer is not property but method**